# NOT getting Correct Date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

hello i am using following code to get date in different days from Current date
but i get wrong results
Please check

```
-(void)calculateDate
{
   // NSArray *arrayOfNumbers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1","42",@"70",@"98", @"183",@"274",@"366",@"487", nil];

    NSArray *arrayOfNumbers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"6",@"10",@"14",@"26",@"39",@"52",@"70", nil];

    NSMutableArray *dateArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i=0; i<[arrayOfNumbers count]; i++) {
        NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        int days=7 *[[arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:i] intValue];

        dayComponent.day = days;// days from above array of weeks 1 then 6 then 14 etc 
         NSCalendar *theCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

        NSDate* dateIncrementByWeek = [theCalendar dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

        [dateArray addObject:dateIncrementByWeek];

    }
    NSLog(@"week dates=%@",dateArray);
}
```

Here it shows wrong output

```
 2014-12-29 18:27:11 +0000",
"2015-02-02 18:27:11 +0000",
"2015-03-02 18:27:11 +0000",
"2015-03-30 18:27:11 +0000",
"2015-06-22 18:27:11 +0000",
"2015-09-21 18:27:11 +0000",
"2015-12-21 18:27:11 +0000",
"2016-04-25 18:27:11 +0000"
```

Comment: Why do you think the output is incorrect? IT looks right to me for the code you posted.

Comment: FYI - no need to allocate a new `NSDateComponents` inside the loop. Just create it once before the loop.

Comment: current date is not 29 December 2014
and then after 7*6=42 days its not suppose to be 2 feb 2015

Comment: The first number in your array is 1. Multiply by 7 and you get 7. Add that to today and you get the 29th.

Comment: oh no...thanks i forget to get it

Answer (score 1):

The output looks right to me, by default NSLog will print date string in UTC +00 format (hence +0000 on the output). Depends on your time zone, it will shows different hours or day than the system's time zone.

Answer (score 1):

> current date is not 29 December 2014 and then after 7*6=42 days its not suppose to be 2 feb 2015

You are not printing the current date, the 29 Dec you see is 7 days after you ran the code.

Try using an array of number objects (`NSNumber`) starting with zero:

```
NSArray *arrayOfNumbers = @[ @0, @1, @4, ... ];
```

*[Note the use of modern shorthands for array construction `@[ ... ]`) and `NSNumber` construction (`@0` etc.)]*

You will now see it starts at the current date (in UTC).

HTH